# error when pip install argostranslate build wheel error

Tags: python, windows, pip

unable to install install argostranslate

installed pip-24.0
using Windows 10
Python 3.12

Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

hoping to have argostranslate without errors, tred fresh Windows build, same result

Comment: ok, turns out it works fine with python 3.9

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

just use python 3.9
not 3.12 for that is too far.
not 3.8 for that is not far enough

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).